# PHP, получить из JSON количество элементов массива

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте. Есть JSON такого вида :

```
{
"response":{
"count":10,
"items":[],
"profiles":[],
"groups":[]
}
}
```

Как из него получить количество элементов, которые содержатся в groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру, можно вот так:

```
$json = '{"response": {"count": 10, "items": [], "profiles": [], "groups": [] } }';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo count($arr['response']['groups']);
```